# jQuery Ajax Form Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an Ajax form. i am caputuring the ID of the form. and when i the ajax call is a success. i want to pass this Id form BeforeSubmit to success. so that i can append the results to a place where i want.

here is the code

```
function StatusComments() {

    $('.status-comment').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });

    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        resetForm: true
    };

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
  var formID = $(this).attr("id");

    }

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
  alert(responseText);
  var formID = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(formID);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form is passed as argument to the success handler:

```
var formID = $form.attr('id');
```

Also I notice that you are using the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and still subscribing to the `.submit` event of the form which is not necessary:

```
$(function() {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        success: showResponse,
        resetForm: true
    };
    $('.status-comment').ajaxForm(options);
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form) {
    var formID = form.attr('id');
    alert(formID);
}
```

Comment: @Darin: i tried with the AjaxSubmit. didnt get it to work :(  i have many .status-comment on the page. i want to pick up the one i clicked

Comment: thanks. when ever i use the ajaxForm alone. i am not able to trigger the success function. so i am using with submit. i dont get any error too

Comment: Well, there must something wrong with your code because that's the way it is supposed to be used. It's much easier.

Comment: ok. is it bcos. i am redenering the html at the form execution end ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly because of this. When you call `.ajaxForm`, the form must be present in the DOM. So if it is a dynamically generated form you need to call the `.ajaxForm` after it is inserted in the DOM.

Comment: oh ok. if i want to send back a piece of code. how can i do it ?

Comment: why we can var dataString = $("#form_crop").serialize(); $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: CDNAPI.baseUrl+"crop.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
     response = eval('('+data+')');
     ProfileWindow.updateapi(response);
    }
   });

Comment: what is the use of using ajaxform ?

Comment: @Rahul Mehta, it is to avoid writing all the code you've shown. You just call `$('#myForm').ajaxForm();` and it takes care of everything necessary to ajaxify the form.

Comment: @Darin why to avoid this and write some other code if this code can work and learn new plugin ?

Comment: @Rahul Mehta, because the more code you have the more possible to make errors and the more code you have to maintain. So why do it when people have already wrote, tested, documented and packaged the code into a plugin ready to be used? Also as you can see the learning curve is relatively easy consisting into writing a single line of code.

Comment: @Rahul Mehta, I see that you are hardcoding the form address, using eval, serializing the form, must not forget to return false to cancel the default form submission, ...

Comment: @Rahul var dataString = $("#form_crop").serialize();  thats the extra. Form Plugin makes life easier. ask me a jQuery Novice. Plugins are around to make life easier after all

Comment: @darin: thanks. just if u could help me understand how to send back the data from the submission. so i can play with it in showResponse. would be great

Comment: In showResponse you have the form. So you can extract whatever data you want from it.

Comment: @Darin i meant. if i want a small html data to be shown. or pull something from the database and show there.